# phpMyAdmin Action icons not displayed

Tags: phpmyadmin, icons

I am using phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.2

I am having trouble making a column in a table not unique.
But in tutorials online I see that my GUI seems to be different.
The online tutorials show Structure like this,

http://www.reg.ca/faq/phpmyadmin6.gif

Where there are different options under Action.
But my own GUI looks like this,

http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/mediagallery/media.php?f=1&s=20150217205314215&i=0&p=0

How can I get phpMyAdmin to look like this?

Thanks,
Shane
Thanks,
Shane

Comment: Why not just learn SQL

Comment: Yes that probably is the thing to do. I was just wondering how to display the action icons. thanks

Comment: @NickBailey that's somewhat unhelpful. user33760 came here looking for an answer to a specific question about how to customize the display of an application; this question isn't even directly about SQL. There certainly are questions on Stack Overflow where the user should learn SQL, but I don't think that's a constructive or friendly comment in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial picture you linked to appears to be a rather old version of phpMYAdmin; version 2 if I recall correctly. What probably happened is that the default display type was changed between when the tutorial was created and the release of 3.5.8.2 (note that even version 3 is generally outdated now).

In version 3, this is controlled by `$cfg['PropertiesIconic']`, which has possible values of true, false, or 'both' (false displays only text, true displays only icons, and 'both' displays both icon and text).

This has changed a bit in version 4 and is now controlled by the configuration setting [`$cfg['ActionLinksMode']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ActionLinksMode). This setting has possible values of 'icons', 'text', or 'both'.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I use phpMyAdmin through my hosting company. So I don't think I have access to $cf.g['PropertiesIconic']. I have actually solved the problem by deleting some indexes and I was able to view the table using DESCRIBE table. Thanks again

Comment: You can always install your own phpMyAdmin in your web root which will operate independently of the one provided by your host. Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're not familiar with doing so, you can check out the documentation at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net and look for the Quick Install section. Basically just download the file and uncompress it to whatever folder you desire in your web root. You may want to configure some settings in `config.inc.php` and that's all covered in the documentation. Good luck!